# How to send message from Content Script to Active Tab in Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am a newbie and creating this Chrome extension and facing a problem when sending a message from Content Script JS to my sidebar JS resource, which is injected into a web page. Here's my *manifest.json* and below the line I use, because I cannot use `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [ "tabs", "storage", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],    

  "browser_action": {      
      "default_title": "Extension"
  },

  "background":{
    "scripts": [ "jquery-3.5.1.min.js", "background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "content_scripts":[
    {
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
      "js": ["jquery-3.5.1.min.js", "content.js", "content-functions.js", "sidebar.js"]
    }
  ],

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "popup.html"
  ]
}
```

**content.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: "pathChanged", value: filter });
```

The problem with this is that ALL tabs get this message and update this info in my sidebar:

**sidebar.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse){
    if(message.type == "pathChanged"){
        $('#path').text(message.value);
    }
})
```

The interesting fact that sidebar.js contains `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` and has no problems with it. So how would I send a message to my sidebar but only to the active tab? I must be missing something, please give me a hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use port-based messaging and reverse the direction: make the connection from the iframe. The iframe is a chrome-extension:// page so it has access to `chrome` API and can see which tab it belongs to.

content script:

```js
let framePort;
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(port => {
  if (port.name === 'frame') {
    // global framePort can be used by code that will run in the future
    framePort = port;
    port.postMessage({foo: 'bar'});
  }
});

// add iframe element and point it to chrome.runtime.getURL('iframe.html')
//...........
```

iframe script:

```js
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(tab => {
  const port = chrome.tabs.connect(tab.id, {name: 'frame', frameId: 0});
  port.onMessage.addListener(msg => {
    if (msg.foo === 'bar') {
      console.log(msg);
    }
  });
});
```